# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1), ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

How to fix this issue.

I will show you every command and output that I tried to use them.

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]     
Hit:3 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                    
Get:4 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]    
Get:5 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Fetched 325 kB in 2s (141 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up kscertrelay-nx-installer (1.0.0.4) ...
No passwd entry for user 'This'
dpkg: error processing package kscertrelay-nx-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kscertrelay-nx-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up kscertrelay-nx-installer (1.0.0.4) ...
No passwd entry for user 'This'
dpkg: error processing package kscertrelay-nx-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kscertrelay-nx-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and

```
sudo dpkg ––configure –a
dpkg: error: need an action option

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install –f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package –f
```

and

```
sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up kscertrelay-nx-installer (1.0.0.4) ...
No passwd entry for user 'This'
dpkg: error processing package kscertrelay-nx-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kscertrelay-nx-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It is hard issue.

Please help me.

Thank in advance

Comment: Did you create any new user "This"?

Comment: No, I am wondering why it gives me that. Maybe it created inadvertently.

Comment: I removed this package `kscertrelay-nx-installer`. Now everything it is OK, I don't know if this step will create another issue for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "this step"? Moreover, with APT commands you're supposed to use hyphen(`-`) not dash(`—`).

Comment: Sorry, I meant removing 'kscertrelay-nx-installer'

Comment: I don't know the purpose of kscertrelay-nx-installer. However, for now. you can post what you did, i.e. how you removed the package as answer.

Comment: What did you mean " you're supposed to use hyphen(-) not dash(—)"? with command?? or another one

Comment: In `sudo apt-get install –f` and `sudo dpkg ––configure –a` you used dashes instead of hyphen (`-`) (observe the lengths). APT and DPKG recognize hyphens. That's why you got errors in both commands. See Wiki article of [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) and [dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation that. I use copy and paste from other people after looking for issues that similar mine and reading their solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is solved by removing the package `kscertrelay-nx-installer` which caused the issue

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove kscertrelay-nx-installer
```